# How to register a browser layer programmatically

Tags: plone, genericsetup

I know that a browser layer can be registered using GenericSetup and one XML file, but I need to make it programmatically.

Is this possible?

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific about your use case? Do you need this for a test?

Comment: yes, this is for a test

Comment: yes I need it for a test, I need to register programmatically a browser layer before the test and run an upgrade step to unregister it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here you go:

```
>>> from plone.browserlayer.tests.interfaces import IMyProductLayer
>>> from plone.browserlayer import utils
>>> IMyProductLayer in utils.registered_layers()
False

>>> utils.register_layer(IMyProductLayer, name='my.product')
>>> IMyProductLayer in utils.registered_layers()
True
```

Copied from https://github.com/plone/plone.browserlayer/blob/master/plone/browserlayer/README.rst

If you just want to have a browser layer present in a test request, you can use the ZCA and directly provide the browser layer interface to a test request:

```
from zope.interface import directlyProvides
from my.product.interfaces import IMyProductBrowserLayer
directlyProvides(self.request, IMyProductBrowserLayer)
```

Comment: Thank you I'll need the first part of your answer.  The only part I think I'll have trouble is that the interface was deleted into my branch, so I'll try to Mock it into test script